# Kafka integration between two micro service which can respond back to the same function initiated the request

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, microservices, reactive

Suppose if we have two micro services communicating using spring Rest Template call and they are exchanging the request and response respectively.Now if I want to use the Kafka in between them to increase throughput. Is it possible to achieve this scenario?

I am able to publish the object as string and produce in Kafka and that is getting listened by the consumer. Now the consumed data is getting processed and sent to the different topic. Now the response should get return in the same function by which the message was produced and published. Is it possible to achieve this using spring Kafka.

How to achieve using request-response pattern.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which "response" are you referring to? The original producer service would need its own consumer of the new topic, so that wouldn't be the same function. Though, spring-kafka has a ReplyingKafkaTemplate that might help